# Переменные переменных

Tags: php

У меня есть  массив

```
$arr = array(
  0 => 100,
  1 => 200
  2 => array(
      0 => 300,
      1 => 400
    )
  )
```

и строка

```
$str = '[2][1]'
```

Почему не работает?

```
$arr{$str} //  NULL
```

Мне надо получить 400

Оно должно работать или нет?

Если нет, то подскажите как правильно обратиться к элементу массива через переменную.

Comment: То есть вы думаете, что [2][1] будет выбирать вам 2 и 1 индексы? Смешно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 10,
        1 => 20,
    )
);
$str = '[0][1]';
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $matches);

$indexes = $matches[0];
$res = $arr;
for($i=0;$i<count($indexes);$i++)
    if (is_array($res) && array_key_exists($indexes[$i], $res))
        $res = $res[$indexes[$i]];
    else
    {
        $res = 'error';
        break;
    }

echo $res;
```

Answer (score 2):

По прочтению https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php.

Похоже, что так можно манипулировать название переменной.
Индексы таким образом манипулировать нельзя.

Не понятно, зачем может понадобиться такая конструкция.

По сути вы пытаетесь создать `eval` - функцию. У меня есть подозрение, что вашу задачу можно решить лучшим способом.

Answer (score 0):

в laravel есть интересный метод array_get()

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-get

в данном примере

```
array_get($arr, '2.1')
```

если заинтересует - можно сорс код посмотреть

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос:

> Мне надо получить 400

Решение:

```
   $var = $str[2][1];
```

Это не переменные переменные это мноомерный массив.